# How to have a variable in the data block of Stan be an array of length J >= 1?

Tags: r, data-structures, stan, rstan

I'm using the following very simple Stan model saved as `model.stan`,

```
data {
  int<lower=1> J;
  real x[J];
}

parameters {
  real mu[J];
  real<lower=0> sigma[J];
}

model {
  sigma ~ inv_gamma(1, 1);
  mu ~ normal(0, 10);
  x ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

In this model I have a single data point `x[j]` that I model as coming from `J` different Normal distributions.

When J > 1, the following R code works perfectly:

```
library(rstan)
model <- stan_model('~/model.stan')
data <- list(J = J, x = runif(J))
stan.fit <- rstan::sampling(model, data=data)
```

However, when J = 1 I get the following error:

```
failed to create the sampler; sampling not done
```

How can I write this Stan model so it works for all J >= 1?

Comment: are you going to compute sigma with one data point?

Comment: I have to say I struggle to understand your model. You estimate two parameters (`mu` and `sigma`) based on one single observation. Is that really what you want to do? Generally, why do you want to have different `sigma`s for different observations? Could you perhaps provide more details as to what you're trying to model/estimate?

Comment: @MauritsEvers It's a silly model that illustrates the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem (and one that is compounded by a bug where the description of the problem is suppressed in **rstan** 2.18.1). If you declare a real array in the data block of a Stan program, the corresponding R object must have a dimension attribute. Thus,

```
stan.fit <- sampling(model, data = list(J = J, x = as.array(runif(J))))
```

does run (although there are many divergent transitions) because `x` has a `dim` attribute that is `J`.